# How to make Django translations accessible from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django, django-i18n

How do you make all of the Django app `locale/<lang>/django.po` translations accessible from Javascript so you can dynamically translate text in Javascript widgets?

According to [these docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-javascript-code) you need to add a URL pattern to your `urls.py` like:

```
urlpatterns += i18n_patterns(
    path("jsi18n/", JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(packages=['myapp1', 'myapp2', ....]), name="javascript-catalog"),
```

and then in your base template's `<head>` add the includes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}"></script>
```

I've done this, and I have Japanese `locale/ja/django.po` (and their compiled .mo) files for every app in my project.

However, when I access the URLs generated by `{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}` (`/admin/jsi18n/`) and `{% url 'javascript-catalog' %}` (`/ja/jsi18n/`) it doesn't contain any of my custom translations.

Why is this? What step in the docs am I missing preventing my translations from being accessible in the Javascript catalog?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Django uses different default domains for it's server side translations ("django") and it's client side translations ("djangojs").

To fix this, I had to explicitly make the JavascriptCatalog use the same domain as the server side. e.g.

```
JavaScriptCatalog.as_view(domain='django', packages=[...])
```